# How can I store or keep in memory loaded images in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this defined:

```
def images_base64(images)
  images.map {|image| image.image}
end
```

and then I load images like this in the haml file:

```
  - images_base64(@document.meta.images).each do |image|
      = image_tag "data:image/png;base64, #{image}", width: '600px'
```

is there a way to store or keep in memory loaded images in rails?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds on the surface like a bad idea without knowing more about why you want to do this? Any reason these images aren't just in say S3? I say that because using something like S3 to serve up files is a much more efficient use of resources than having Rails shuffle huge files back in its responses.

Also when you say "in memory", that can mean a lot of things. Like you could mean cache this giant list of image tags in Memcache or Redis. So you could fragment cache around images_base64 in your HAML file with something like `cache document do` That would store a chunk of image_tag html with the base64 image strings in your cache store.

And this is a worse idea: you could memoize the images into memory. Here's a link on doing memoization with parameters: http://gavinmiller.io/2013/advanced-memoization-in-ruby/. I only mention this because you said "memory loaded". But I really don't think you want this approach.